# Angular js Material md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have being trying to resolve this issue for more than 9 hours but have no idea how to solve it even in angular js material demo site this problem is occuring.

My problem is with body scrollbar getting hidden when the `md-select` dropbox is open. Does anyone know how can i get both scrollbar working at the same time. I am using angular js material 1.1.0

Here is a demo with the issue.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayePPa

this is the example.I am talking about

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding some information in a comment.

Comment: @danny, I think this is a default functionality, it would mean, you need to modify the source code of `angular-material` javascript file! Why do you want to do this? any specific reason, maybe there is a workaround than this method!

Comment: I have a functionality of dropdown with name and on body side i have information if user want to see @NarenMurali

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a **select**, the rule :

```
position: fixed;
```

Is applied to the `body` so the scroll-bar is removed, so you need to override this rule by this one :

```
body {
    position: static !important;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMKpZO) is your codepen with the scroll-bar.

Comment: i tried that but if you scroll down little bit your menu will messed up if its small drop down

Comment: Yes but it will be a bigger job if you want to resolve all side effects of enabling the scroll-bar :/